# Can I omit "zu urteilen" in the construction (etwas nach zu urteilen)?

Tags: sentence-structure

Please consider the following sentences:

> - Den Wolken nach zu urteilen, wird es offensichtlich regnen.
> - Dem Wetterbericht nach zu urteilen wird es Morgen schön.

Can I say instead:

> - Den Wolken nach wird es offensichtlich regnen.
> - Dem Wetterbericht nach wird es Morgen schön.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meaning of the sentences is equivalent and both versions are fine and common.

> etwas nach zu urteilen

You can only use this when referring to a thing or concept which can in the widest possible sense be judged or interpreted. So you would not use it when simply referring to or quoting a statement either, but one can use it, if it is a more convoluted one which needs possibly interpretation. You cannot use it when referring to a person themselves. Concerning cloud observations or weather forecasts: both is perfectly fine. So if one wants to make a distinction, it could be along these lines:

> Max nach sind sie gestern ins Kino gegangen

According to Max... / Going by Max' words...

> Nach Max' Erzählung zu Vampiren zu urteilen, wird er Dr. Frankenstein schon gesehen haben. (but Max did not explicitly talk about that movie)

Judging Max' story telling about vampires... / If Max' talking about vampires is anything to go by... / Going by Max' words...

Comment: Many thanks, I really appreciate it. Could you please elaborate on this: //So you would not use it when simply referring to or quoting a statement either, but one can use it, if it is a more convoluted one which needs possibly interpretation.//

Comment: I amended the last examples with translations in an attempt to clarify this